# XML -- how to define and use nodes to be referred in multiple places in the same file

Tags: xml, dom

i've got some items, say

```
<item name = "this", price = "that"/>
<item name = "this2", price = "that2"/>
<item name = "this3", price = "that3"/>
...
```

that i'll use in multiple places. so, i'll have an XML node with item `this2`
above within it

```
<group id = "5">
    <items> 
        <!-- this2 here--> 
    <items/>
<group/>
```

and another:

```
<group id = "87">
    <items> 
        <!-- this5 and this44 here--> 
    <items/>
<group/>
```

how to define items to be referenced like this from whereever needed in the same XML file? and once thats done, how to refer to them?

TIA.

ps.: i'm only interested in coming up with an accurate XML structure so that i can read it with a DOM parser. I'm not looking to define an XSD schema.

//===============================

i'm looking to define, say item `this2` at one place 
and refer to that description of it from each group it's supposed to go in.

this as a better alternative to typing the `<item>` tag for `this2` and 
copy-pasting it into each `<group>` tag it's supposed to go in.

how is this done all in the same XML file the easiest way?
some heavily structured way isn't worth it-- my data isn't that lenghty or complicated. 
however - there must be a better way of doing this than copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to declare entities in the internal subset and read it with a DOM parser.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY this '<item name="this" price="that"/>'>
<!ENTITY this2 '<item name="this2" price="that2"/>'>
<!ENTITY this3 '<item name="this3" price="that3"/>'>
]>
<doc>
    <group id="5">
        <items>
            &this2;
        </items>
    </group>
    <group id="87">
        <items>
            &this;
            &this3;
        </items>
    </group>
</doc>
```

You might be able to move the entity declarations off to a separate file and reference them with a parameter entity, but that might not work for all DOM parsers.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY % ents SYSTEM "ents.mod">
%ents;
]>
<doc>
    <group id="5">
        <items>
            &this2;
        </items>
    </group>
    <group id="87">
        <items>
            &this;
            &this3;
        </items>
    </group>
</doc>
```